# Making functions that only do one thing

Tags: python

I'm practicing writing functions that do only one thing. I'm getting stuck with the below functions. `play_games` is what the user calls to run the whole program. Ideally, it should only have the call to the `play_many_games` method which is in one of the program's classes.

But if I don't also add the line that calls the `prepare_reports` function, then the reports will never get taken care of. How do I "do reports and games" if I insist on only having functions that do one thing?

Is the bottom line that we need a `main` function that can do more than one thing (e.g. a main function that can do both games and reports calls)?

```
def play_games(number_of_games):
    games_engine = prepare_reports(number_of_games)
    games_engine.play_many_games(number_of_games)


def prepare_reports(number_of_games):
    report_requests = []
    if number_of_games <= 100:
        report_on_game = GameReport()
        report_requests.append(report_on_game)
    report_on_many_games = ManyGamesReport()
    report_requests.append(report_on_many_games)
    return GamesEngine(*report_requests)
```

Comment: Having a main function that does nothing but drive the process and call other functions, _is_ a function that only does one thing. I suggest you create one.

Comment: @martineau I hadn't thought of doing only one thing in that sense. I think this is the answer.

Comment: okcapp: So do I. `;¬)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a main function that does nothing but drive the process and call other functions, *is* a function that only does one thing. I suggest you create one.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, since there's not much of a point in declaring `games_engine`:

```
def play_games(number_of_games):
    prepare_reports(number_of_games).play_many_games(number_of_games)

def prepare_reports(number_of_games):
    report_requests = []
    if number_of_games <= 100:
        report_on_game = GameReport()
        report_requests.append(report_on_game)
    report_on_many_games = ManyGamesReport()
    report_requests.append(report_on_many_games)
    return GamesEngine(*report_requests)
```

However, what you showed us is technically a function doing only one thing. You see, by declaring `games_engine = prepare_reports(number_of_games)`, you are just making your code easier to read.